# Prepend while refiling

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

When we refile, the refiled stuff goes to the end of the heading under which it is being refiled.

Can we get the refiled stuff to go to the top, instead?

This can be easily done while capturing. I can write a custom template and with `:prepend t` instruction, the captured stuff goes to the top of the heading under which it is getting captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc string of `org-refile` says:

> At the target location, the entry is filed as a subitem of the
> target heading.  Depending on ‘org-reverse-note-order’, the new
> subitem will either be the first or the last subitem.

If you don't want to set it permanently, you can let-bind it in your own `org-refile` wrapper command:

```el
(defun my/org-refile ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-reverse-note-order t))
    (call-interactively #'org-refile)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Especially, the function to set it up temporarily will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `org-capture-refile (C-c C-w)` to respect `:prepend` from the `org-capture-templates` definition, one option, and the one that worked best for me, was to create an advice like the following:

```lisp
    (defun my/org--capture-refile (orig-fun &rest args)
      (let ((org-reverse-note-order (org-capture-get :prepend 'local)))
        (apply orig-fun args)))

    (advice-add #'org-capture-refile :around 'my/org--capture-refile)
```

This way, `org-reverse-note-order` is temporarily overridden based on `:prepend` from the template.